# Short toHexString

Tags: java

There are methods `Integer.toHexString()` and `Long.toHexString()`. For some reason they didn't implement `Short.toHexString()`.

What is the canonical method converting Short to a hex string?

It's not possible to use `Integer.toHexString()` because `Integer.toHexString(-33)` equals `ffffffdf` which is not a short value.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to substr the 4 least-significant hex characters (from Integer.toHexString)? In the *posted* case it would be valid (`ffdf`), and I *think* it would universally hold as both are two's complement ..

Comment: Actually, even this `System.out.format("%x", -33)` gives `ffffffdf`. I guess it might have something to do with representation of primitives in memory.

Comment: Formatter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) can do convertion, but it is pretty much overkill.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If in your system `short` is represented as 16Bit you can also simply do the following.

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(-33 & 0xffff);
```

Comment: Aww!! Why didn't I thought that.. +1 to you. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you can simply take the two least-significant bytes.**

This is a basic feature of the [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your `Integer.toHexString` in to a hex string for short value.

`Integer` is of `32 bit`, and `Short` is of `16 bit`. So, you can just remove the 16 most significant bit from `Hex String` for `short value` converted to `integer`, to get a `Hex String` for `Short`.

```
Integer -> -33 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11011111  == Hex = ffffffdf
Short   -> -33 =                   11111111 11011111  == Hex =     ffdf
```

So, just take the last `4` characters of `Hex String` to get what you want.

So, what you want is: -

```
Short sh = -33;
String intHexString = Integer.toHexString(sh.intValue());
String shortHexString = intHexString.substring(4);
```

I think that would work.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work for a short

```
UnicodeFormatter.charToHex((char)c);
```

You can download UniocdeFormatter.java here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/examples/UnicodeFormatter.java

Answer (score 0):

Not the simplest way to do this, but I you can get it done by converting to a byte array then converting that to a hex string.

```
 short a = 233;
 byte[] ret = new byte[2];

 ret[0] = (byte)(a & 0xff);
 ret[1] = (byte)((a >> 8) & 0xff);

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (byte b : ret) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
 }
```

I think that will pretty much do it.