# Convert json decimal number to short with hexadecimal value

Tags: java, android, json

I have a `JSONObject` that contains a string with a decimal value like this:

```
private static RegisterIn ParseRegisterIn(JSONObject object)
{
    RegisterIn toReturn = new RegisterIn();
    try {
        toReturn.setUsername(object.getString("username"));
        toReturn.setCertificate(new Short(Integer.toHexString(object.get("certificate"))));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

The `certificate` object value is **15879** which corresponds to **3E07** in hexadecimal. I want to recover it from the JSONObject and save it in a `short` attribute. And IT HAS to be like that.

I've tried to access the parameter and recover it as posted above, but I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3e07"

How can I get this decimal value, convert it to hexadecimal, and save it in a short value?

**NOTE:** the

```
toReturn.setCertificate(...)
```

is `short` type.

Comment: Did you try `Short.parseShort(object.get("certificate"))`?

Comment: No didn't... I'm gonna try...

Comment: It says it has to be converted to string...

Comment: you may also try:  `object.getInt("certificate")`

Comment: @Sonhja if it say has to be converted to String, u can use `Short.parseShort(object.get("certificate").toString())`

Comment: I used `getString` instead of `get`, but then the short is too long... :S

Comment: @Sonhja why don't you read it as integer then convert it to String hexidecimal? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356984/short-tohexstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use,

```
Short.parseShort(object.getString("certificate"), 16);
```

Comment: it says it has to be cast to String, but if I convert it, then it fails. And if I don't, it doesn't compile.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it work. You have to write `getString` and not `get` by its own. But now I get the following error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range for short: "15879"

Answer (score 1):

Use `Short.parseShort(object.getString("certificate"), 16);`

Comment: I can recover the `15879 `value, but when converting to short, then it says it's too long. I should convert it to hexadecimal first...

Comment: Weird thought short maximum value is `32,767`. Can you change `setCertificate` return method?